# Clustering tiled surfaces in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am new to clustering. The problem I have at hand is this:
I have a tiled surface of fixed size (pretty much like a chess board) where each tile can take a continuous value (called height) between 0 and 1. I have (let's say) 20 such surfaces. I need to create clusters of surfaces that have similar looking groups of height profiles or shapes.

What would be the best strategy to define a metric (similarity or distance matrix) that can be used to cluster these surfaces into similar looking groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can view distance between two matrices d(A,B) as a matrix norm ||A-B|| and then take any of many [matrix norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm).

Comment: I also tried using the distance matrix where distance = ||A-B||. However, I still see that the clusters have some mix. I am not sure if norm of difference of two surfaces will capture the spatial nature of the heights. For example: two surfaces (say B and C) with similar looking height profiles but in different directions will probably have same distance value with respect to a third surface i.e. ||A-B||  == ||A-C||.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe doing some rotation so that to somehow align those surfaces prior distance calculation would help?

Comment: BTW, I used hc <- hclust(d,method="average") on the distance matrix. Is there any other recommended method to use?

Comment: Hi Aby: I have a spatial data of more than 300 surfaces that I need to cluster (X,Y,Z) . Let me know how you solved this problem. Thanks!